# React Native - Keyboard dismissed after each keystroke in TextInput

Tags: react-native

I am using a 3rd party library called `react-native-scrollable-navigation-bar` which enable a TextInput to be attached to the bottom of the header navigation bar. You can refer to [this example usage](https://zobeirhamid.github.io/react-native-scrollable-navigation-bar/examples/search-bar). For my usage, I need to declare a state in the parent component which is updated `onChangeText`, as an example:

```
import { AppleStyle } from 'react-native-scrollable-navigation-bar';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

function Example(props) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  function Placeholder(props) {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 200, margin: 50, backgroundColor: 'grey' }} />
    );
  }

  function SnapComponent() {
    return (
      <SearchBar
        ref={inputRef}
        platform="ios"
        value={query}
        onChangeText={setQuery}
        lightTheme
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        onFocus={() => {
          if (ref.current) {
            ref.current.focus();
          }
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          if (ref.current) {
            ref.current.blur();
          }
        }}
        containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
      <AppleStyle
        headerHeight={300}
        title={'Hello World'}
        SnapComponent={SnapComponent}
        snapHeight={72}
        ref={ref}
        onBlur={() => {
          if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.blur();
          }
        }}
      >
        <Placeholder />
        <Placeholder />
        <Placeholder />
        <Placeholder />
      </AppleStyle>
  );
}
```

However, when the `TextInput\SearchBar` is in focus, the keyboard will be dismissed after each keystroke.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your SnapComponent (and possibly the Placeholder components) are inside of your main component Example. This is causing a full re-rendering everytime you input text. To solve this problem, move the components outside of the parent.